# Set TransitRadius on Android RouteWaypoints

Tags: android, here-api

Is there any way to set the TransitRadius on RouteWaypoints?

described on https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html

```java
/* Initialize a CoreRouter */
CoreRouter coreRouter = new CoreRouter();

/* Initialize a RoutePlan */
mRoutePlan = new RoutePlan();

/*
* Initialize a RouteOption.HERE SDK allow users to define their own parameters for the
* route calculation,including transport modes,route types and route restrictions etc.Please
* refer to API doc for full list of APIs
*/
RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
/* Other transport modes are also available e.g Pedestrian */
routeOptions.setTransportMode( RouteOptions.TransportMode.TRUCK );
/* Disable highway in this route. */
routeOptions.setHighwaysAllowed( false );
/* Calculate the shortest route available. */
routeOptions.setRouteType( RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST );
/* Calculate 1 route. */
routeOptions.setRouteCount( 1 );
/* Finally set the route option */
mRoutePlan.setRouteOptions( routeOptions );

/* Define waypoints for the route */
/* START: 4350 Still Creek Dr */
RouteWaypoint startPoint = new RouteWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(49.259149, -123.008555));
/* END: Langley BC */
RouteWaypoint destination = new RouteWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(49.073640, -122.559549));

/* Add both waypoints to the route plan */
mRoutePlan.addWaypoint( startPoint );
mRoutePlan.addWaypoint( destination );
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using RouteWaypoint.setSelectiveMatchingRadius() method. This would expand the radius for matching the road element ([documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteWaypoint.html#setSelectiveMatchingRadius-int-)) which is the same function as Transit Radius in the HERE Routing REST API.

Comment: seriously?!? nearly 2 yeas later... ‍♂️